# Are the last three job reaction icons needed?

Tags: discussion, support, stack-overflow-jobs

I just came noticed the new 'Reactions to this job' feature and I'm questioning some of the reaction choices available.

[image]

I can understand the first three, but I'm not sure how the unicorn and the laughing reaction have any relevance regarding a job and arguably the sad face as that can be replaced by the thumbs down.

I can't even figure what the unicorn or laughing reaction is meant to mean in the context a job.

- What does the unicorn and laughing reaction mean in this context?
- If they have no relevance should (can) they be removed?